# HTML - Anchor points to ID of parent's sbiling element

Tags: html

Is it possible to point the anchors inside an element that points to (that) element's sibling?

**index.html**

```
<body class="container">
    <object id="home" class="page_container" type="text/html" data="pages/home.html"></object> <!-- contains the navigation -->
    <object id="about" class="page_container" type="text/html" data="pages/about.html"></object>
</body>
```

**home.html**

```
<a class="nav-item medium primary-font-color" href="#about">
    About
</a> <!-- expecting to scroll down to about page -->
```

Here's a Plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/SWzTeUxHxWIHZw81VLde?p=preview

Comment: My suggestion would be not to use `<object>` (or (i)frames for the matter) to include HTML like this in the first place. It would be better to use a server-side include mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have child HTML documents (`home.html`, `about.html`) in one big parent HTML document (where your "working about" scroller is situated).

Since the child document's `#about` anchor would be looking for an `#about` element in the scope of `home.html`, it won't scroll to the parent HTML document's `#about` element, nor will it find its "sibling" HTML document's `#about`.

In general, if you're not importing external HTML documents, it is possible to link from an arbitrarily-placed anchor element to any object in the HTML page that has the desired id.